# how to use abstract class with template in typescript and call it

Tags: typescript

```
abstract class <T> abs {

  public name:T;

  constructor(){


   }

}

class b extends abs {

constructor(){

super <T> ();

}

}
```

This is not working.

It is throwing error: "Unable to parse the file"

How to call the abstract class from derived class with passing types.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax should be something like this:

```
abstract class Abstract<T> {
    public name: T;

    constructor() {
    }
}


class NonAbstract<T> extends Abstract<T> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```